# Global variables with C++ in multiple files

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, c

I'm not a C++ programmer (but I have used regular C code for implementing low-level machine language equivalent SW for some time), and after trying to modify an existing cC+ program to do what I need (and failing), I've decided to rewrite parts of the code in plain C code.

But to be able to use the data, I need to create some variables that have to be accessible to parts of the existing C++ code.

When I declare a global variable (`extern int variable name;`) outside the main program, the compile fails because the references to the global variable aren't within the scope of the cpp parts of the program.

I don't program with multiple files myself, so I was wondering if I need to globally declare the same variables as part of each cpp program that needs to have access to the variables? Is there a another/better way?

Comment: [How do I use extern to share variables between source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1433204/669576)

Comment: Why not just write C code but still name the file .cpp and let the C++ compiler compile it.

Comment: So you know, using global variables is not best way to compose object oriented code.  And I know where you are coming from (embedded processors with little room for extravagant C++ constructs).  But contemporary embedded processors are way more powerful than the venerable 8051 of yesterday.  And C++ is a great way to compartmentalize and isolate features to the extent they really only need to be tested once.  Then reused over and over again.  Give it some thought before you force old methods where newer approaches are starting to make sense and save money.

Comment: I just deleted my 3rd attempt to answer your question.  There are just too many assumptions that need to be made about your existing C++ code as well as your attempts to bring it all together using ordinary C.  I keep coming back to it would be better if you just learned C++.  I'll just say this, if the existing C++ classes still work for you, you should be able to use them using only formally passed values.  Why do you need to use global variable on top of that?

Comment: First, I haven't written the c code yet, just declared the new global variables, but it won't compile.

Comment: I understand the reusability of object orientated code, but I've never written any.....I really don't want to learn right now, just make some mods if possible, but because that was not successful, I thought I'd write one of the c++ parts in c code, but the global issue is stopping me. I'd really love to learn c++, but I need to get this code  modified for a project, and can't delay it for likely some months of learning......BTW, I'm 70+ years old, and have been a computer professional since 1968, mostly doing HW design......something about old dogs and new tricks, I think.

Answer (score 5):

When using multiple source files you need to use header files to share things between them.

myproject.h:

```
#ifndef __myproject_h__
#define __myproject_h__
extern int aGlobalVariable;
#endif
```

myNewCode.c

```
#include "myproject.h"
int aGlobalVariable;
```

modifiedOldCode.cpp

```
#include "myproject.h"
```

This way the header file defines the variable as an extern in all of your c / cpp files so that it is visible to all of them but the variable is only actually declared and memory allocated for it in one place, in the .c file.
Similarly any functions that you want to be visible in both files should be declared in the headerfile (e.g. `void myfunction(int x);`) but the actual definitions should be somewhere in the .c or .cpp files.
The #ifndef and #define lines in the header as there so that if the header somehow gets included twice you don't get lots of redefinition errors.

There is nothing strange about c++ and globals, a global defined this way is global to everything, it doesn't matter what object you're in or how things are scoped. This can however have some strange effects since there is only ever one copy of a global while you can possibly have multiple instances of the c++ class that uses it. This can cause some consistency related issues if you aren't careful. Whether you need to worry about this or not depends very much on the nature of the code.

Comment: Thanks.....that's the information I needed.....hopefully I'll be able to implement it.....